# Rails Paperclip, DRY configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, dry

In order to DRY up my code for attachments pictures, I created an initializer to override the `@default_options` variable used by Paperclip.

This way, I don't have to specify again and again the url, path and storage I want.

I'd like to go a step further and include the validation in it but I can't make it work...

Any Idea?

EDIT 1: I want at least to validate both presence and size.

EDIT 2: Part of my current code

```
module Paperclip
 class Attachment
   def self.default_options
     if Rails.env != "production"
       @default_options = {
         :url => "/assets/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:normalized_name",
         :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:normalized_name",
         :default_style => :original,
         :storage       => :filesystem,
         :whiny         => Paperclip.options[:whiny] || Paperclip.options[:whiny_thumbnails]
         }
      else
       ...
      end
   end
 end
```

`normalized_name` is an outside function, feat: http://blog.wyeworks.com/2009/7/13/paperclip-file-rename

EDIT 3:

This blog: http://omgsean.com/2009/02/overriding-paperclip-defaults-for-your-entire-rails-app/ presnents the `default_options` hash with a `validations` key.

So it could be possible, not found yet though.

Comment: might want to show what you have and what you've tried

Comment: I don't really see much of a question here. What's wrong with the standard validations for presence and size?

Comment: I'd like to put them in the default_options hash

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to set the filetype in here? (convert everything to PNG for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to move the validations into a `default_options` hash (as these validations are performed outside the attachment class (inside a paperclip module). My thought is that if you have the same validations across all your models, you might need to look into using inheritance to decrease code duplication. I would advise against moving validations into an initializer.

Comment: I wonder why http://omgsean.com/2009/02/overriding-paperclip-defaults-for-your-entire-rails-app/, referes to a validations key

Comment: Does it work? Try it... I've looked through the source code fairly extensively in the past and don't see any reference to it...

Comment: Indeed I also tried to override ‘module InstanceMethods‘ without success. Any clue?

Comment: I think your going to need to subclass your models and include the validation code in the parent model.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'll try and confirm your solution asap, +1 anyway ;)